# Weird text size in IE10 for Windows Phone 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm experiencing some real weirdness with text sizes in IE for WP8.  There are two ways you can test and see this: use the WP8 Emulator built into IE11 (Win8.1) or use the IE in WP8.

To see the problem, check out this website: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50150377/test.html

The text is simply comprised of `<H2>` and `<P>` tags.  There is a top DIV that spans 400px, and two bottom DIV's that float left and span 200px each.

If you go to this page in any standard browser, you'll see the H2 font-sizes are consistent, and the other text size is consistent.

If you visit the page in IE11's WP8 Emulator or in WP8's version of IE, you'll notice that the top text is much larger than the lower text.

Is it supposed to act this way?  Is there a work-around that anyone knows of?  This is causing some real problems for my designs.  I've tried using relative and absolute font-sizes, but it makes no difference.

Here are some screenshots and the code I'm using.  I've minimized the code to almost nothing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**Rendering on WP8:**

[image: Rendering in WP8]

**Rendering on Desktop (IE, FF, Chrome):**

[image: Rendering on the Desktop]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { font-family:arial; }
        .infoBox h2 { font-size:14px; }
        .infoBox p { font-size: 12px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="infoBox" style="width:400px">
            <!-- This text is MUCH larger in IE for WP8 -->

            <h2>THIS IS A TEST</h2>
            <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  </p>
            <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  </p>
        </div>

        <div class="infoBox" style="width:200px;float:left;height:400px;">
            <!-- This text will be smaller in IE for WP8 -->

            <h2>THIS IS A TEST</h2>
            <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  </p>
            <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  </p>
        </div>

        <div class="infoBox" style="width:200px;float:left;height:400px;">
            <!-- This text will also be smaller in IE for WP8 -->

            <h2>THIS IS A TEST</h2>
            <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  </p>
            <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like adding this `<META>` tag fixes the problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Only thing is I took off the user-scalable=no.  It prevents users from enlarging or shrinking the rendered view, which is undesirable.

Comment: Indeed, I should have mentioned that.  I'm updating my answer to have that removed...